# cut or awk command to print first field of first row

Tags: linux, bash, unix, awk

I am trying print the first field of the first row of an output. Here is the case. I just need to print only `SUSE` from this output.

```
# cat /etc/*release

SUSE Linux Enterprise Server 11 (x86_64)
VERSION = 11
PATCHLEVEL = 2
```

Tried with `cat /etc/*release | awk {'print $1}'` but that print the first string of every row

```
SUSE
VERSION
PATCHLEVEL
```

Answer (score 252, accepted):

Specify [`NR`](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Auto_002dset.html#index-NR-variable-1) if you want to capture output from selected rows:

```
awk 'NR==1{print $1}' /etc/*release
```

An alternative (*ugly*) way of achieving the same would be:

```
awk '{print $1; exit}'
```

An efficient way of getting the *first string* from a specific line, say line 42, in the output would be:

```
awk 'NR==42{print $1; exit}'
```

Comment: @jaypal I also thought of adding a `tac file | awk 'END{print $1}'` but then realized it might be a bit too much.

Comment: Though that would make your *ugly* solution look **remarkably** prettier against the proposed *hideous* solution!

Comment: It not `ugly`.  Its even better, since on a large file, it will save lots of time by exit on found and stops processing.

Comment: @Jotne I termed it ugly simply because `NR==1` was _implicit_.  Added another example in the answer that probably clarifies a bit more.

Comment: @devnull I do know, but OPs requirement is clear `print the first string of the first row of an output` so here the `exit` would be just fine.

Comment: @Jotne You know it, so it's perhaps obvious.  To someone new, it might not be.

Comment: is `exit` on the third example (after specifying `NR`) really necessary?

Answer (score 25):

Specify the **Line Number** using `NR` built-in variable.

```
awk 'NR==1{print $1}' /etc/*release
```

Answer (score 11):

try this:

```
head -1 /etc/*release | awk '{print $1}'
```

Answer (score 5):

```
df -h | head -4 | tail -1 | awk '{ print $2 }'
```

Change the numbers to tweak it to your liking.

Or use a while loop but thats probably a bad way to do it.

Comment: Now that's a nifty hack!

Answer (score 4):

You could use the `head` instead of `cat`:

```
head -n1 /etc/*release | awk '{print $1}'
```

Answer (score 3):

```
sed -n 1p /etc/*release |cut -d " " -f1
```

if tab delimited:

```
sed -n 1p /etc/*release |cut -f1
```

Answer (score 3):

awk, sed, pipe, that's heavy

```
set `cat /etc/*release`; echo $1
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
sed 'NUMq;d'  /etc/*release | awk {'print $1}'
```

where NUM is line number

```
ex. sed '1q;d'  /etc/*release | awk {'print $1}'
```

Comment: This would print entire 1st line and not 1st field as OP stated.

Comment: Answer saras che pan thodu laambu che. Khali `sed` thi pan kari sakiye - `sed -r '1s/([^ ]+) .*/\1/;q'  /etc/*release` `:)`

Answer (score 0):

the most code-golfy way i could think of to print first line only in `awk` :

> ```
> awk '_{exit}--_'    # skip the quotations and make it just
>                     #   awk _{exit}--_
>                     #
>                     # if u're feeling adventurous
> ```

1. first pass through exit block, `"_"` is undefined,
   so it fails and skips over for row 1.
2. then the decrementing of the same counter will make
   it "**TRUE**" in `awk`'s eyes (anything not empty string
   or numeric zero is considered "true" in their agile boolean sense). that same counter also triggers default action of print for row 1.

   ```
   —- incrementing… decrementing… it's same thing, 
      merely direction and sign inverted.
   ```
3. then finally, at start of row 2, it hits criteria to
   enter the action block, which instructs it to instantly
   exit, thus performing essentially the same functionality as

> ```
> awk '{ print; exit }'
> ```

… in a slightly less verbose manner. For a single line print, it's not even worth it to set `FS` to skip the field splitting part.

using that concept to print just **1st** row **1st** field :

> ```
> awk '_{exit} NF=++_'
> awk '_++{exit} NF=_'
> ```

Answer (score 0):

```
awk 'NR==1&&NF=1' file
grep -om1 '^[^ ]\+' file

# multiple files
awk 'FNR==1&&NF=1' file1 file2
```