# grab specific part of the output of the --version of qrencode

Tags: bash, text, awk, head

I try to grab just the version number of `qrencode` but it does not work. Any idea why?

```
$ qrencode --version | head -1 | awk '{print $3}'
qrencode version 3.4.4
Copyright (C) 2006-2012 Kentaro Fukuchi
```

I am quite confused because this sort of techniques use to work fine with most packages:

```
$ gzip --version | head -1 | awk '{print $2}'
1.6
```

**Edit**: thanks for the help. This is because for `qrencode` the output of `--version` is print to stderr instead of stdout. According so answer comments this is common to some extend. A bit weird to me, but fair enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may redirect stderr to stdout:

```
qrencode --version 2>&1 | head -1 |  awk '{print $3}'
                   ^^^^
```

Output: `3.4.4`

If you want to get rid of `head -1` and get the same results with `awk` use

```
qrencode --version 2>&1 | awk 'NR==1{print $3}'
```

See [cut or awk command to print first field of first row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22190902) for details.

Comment: Ok. So does that mean that qrencode is using the stderr for printing the version instead of the stdout? Weird. Is that common?

Comment: @Zorglub29 From my experience, this is common to some extent.

Answer (score 2):

Could you please try following.

```
qrencode --version 2>&1 | awk 'FNR==1{print $3;exit}'
```