# Read variable from first line and print the entire file then the variable

Tags: awk, text-processing

Want to read a variable from first line, then print the rest and the variable at the end.
Input file:

```
2020,sunday,night
2012,wednesday,afternoon
2014,saturday,morning
```

output:

```
2020,sunday,night
2012,wednesday,afternoon
2014,saturday,morning
2020
```

I've tried something like this, but doesn't work well:

```
cat days.txt | awk 'NR==1{mydata=$1} {print} {print mydata}'
2020,sunday,night
2020,sunday,night
2012,wednesday,afternoon
2020,sunday,night
2014,saturday,morning
2020,sunday,night
```

Answer (score 0):

Found the way to do it:

```
cat days.txt | awk -F, 'NR==1{year=$1}{print}END{print year}'
2020,sunday,night
2012,wednesday,afternoon
2014,saturday,morning
2020
```

Thanks to [cut or awk command to print first field of first row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22190902/cut-or-awk-command-to-print-first-field-of-first-row)

Comment: `awk -F, 'NR==1{year=$1}{print}END{print year}' days.txt` -- get rid of the unnecessary use of `cat` (*UUOc*)